# Where can I find documentation for the 'header' event?

Tags: node.js

ConnectJS uses the [res.on('header'...](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/responseTime.html) event to do some post processing on the response.  I have searched far and wide in the NodeJS documentation, but cannot find this event mentioned anywhere.  Can someone point me in the direction of some documentation for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`header` event is not native for node.js. This event [provided by](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/lib/patch.js#L67) `connect`. [Here is](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/gh-pages/tests.md#header-event) some documentation.